# Pascal's Triangle Python

Tags: python, pascals-triangle

So I've been trying to work at making a proper Pascal's triangle but all the sources that I've found seem to either use def's or input statements at the start of the code. It's a pretty basic question, but how can I put an input statement into this program to where it asks "What is the height of the triangle." So I can always be able to change the outcome to whatever height I want it to be. Thanks.

```
def new_row(n):
    trow = [1]
    y = [0]
    for x in range(max(n,0)):
        print(trow)
        trow=[l+r for l,r in zip(trow+y, y+trow)]
    return n>=1
new_row(6)
```

Comment: Something like this `n = raw_input("Enter the height:")` and then `n=int(n)`

Comment: Note that if you are using Python 3 instead of `raw_input` simply use `input`

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm embarrassed that I thought I'd found a bigger problem for myself when in reality it was such a simple solution. Nonetheless, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can read this link : [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431704/python-formatting-my-pascal-triangle)
can custom from parameter.

or this code :

```
import math as mt

def combine(n,r):
    ncr=(mt.factorial(n))/((mt.factorial(r))*(mt.factorial(n-r)))
    return ncr

def pascal():
  i=int(input("Enter index: "))
  z=len(str(int(combine(i,(i//2)))))
  nosp=z*i

  for k in range(0,i+1):
    sttr=''
    for l in range(0,k+1):
        sttr+=(" "*(2*z-len(str(int(combine(k,l))))))+str(int(combine(k,l)))
    isp=len(str(i))-len(str(k))+1
    print(isp*" "+str(k)+": "+nosp*" "+sttr)
    nosp-=z

print("Pascal's Triangle.")
pascal()
print("Done!")
```